# Split tunnel Nortel VPN on mac

Tags: mac, vpn

I have the Apani Nortel VPN client on my mac.  Unfortunately all the traffic is routed over the VPN when I use this client.  I want to view the routing table and modify it so my non-corporate traffic just routes over my local gateway.

However, for some reason I can't see how the routing is working.  ifconfig isn't showing me anything about my VPN (at least I don't see it).  I can't tell what my gateway is.

I did this for a cisco VPN a while back and it worked:

sudo route delete mygatewayIP
sudo route add 0.0.0.0 myhomeroutergatewayIP
sudo 10.0.0.0 mycorporategatewayIP